# Magento configurable product search issue

Tags: magento

I am having a problem in search functionality.

I have two configurable products Say A and B.
A's associated products are A1, A2 and A3 similarly
B's are B1, B2 and B3.

In catalog search I want the products to be searched by 
manufacturers; its options are M1, M2 and M3.

For config products A and B I have set manufacturers as M1.
So when i search the product i get count 2 for M1.

[image]

The thing is when any associated product of A (or B)
say A1 is set to manufacturer M2; then  A shows up in 
both the options of M1 and M2 in the Layered navigation.

[image: m]

So while filtering the configurable products the attributes of 
associated products is also considered, i want to consider only
the configurable product's attribute.

Please help me out.

Comment: Try removing manufacture from the configurable product and only add manufacturer in the associated products.

Comment: This might work but i dont want it that way. The requirement is such that for configurable products both parent and the child products will have the manufacturer attribute set. It is used for ERP which i dont have control over.

Comment: I am afraid that can't be done then without custom coding.

Comment: I have made custom coding based on http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5371/ignoring-child-product-attributes-in-layered-navigation..but its not helping

Answer (score 0):

Simple for the configurable product make another attribute named manufacturer2 and for associated product use standard manufacturer. From your CMR import the same value to both attributes. 
In config of attribute manufacturer2 set not visible in search and layered navigation.

Lately in product view page or list page, you can manually set visible manufacturer2 and hide manufacturer.